# PHP LDAP secondary query after obtaining dn

Tags: php, ldap

Im working on adding authentication to one of my dashboards.

My setup is a little unique I believe. We use a service account to obtain the DN of a user, this query works as expected. We then bind a second time using that new dn instead of the service account. This also works, so technically at this point, the user is properly authenticated.

I'm trying to perform a second ldap_search after succesful bind as the dn I pull from the first query. This is unfortunately giving me the results of the previous ldap_search. This is what I'm not understanding.

```
if($bind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $ldap_dn, $adminpass)) {

    // valid
    echo "bound to ldap<BR>\n";
    $filter = "(&(objectclass=user)(samaccountname=$user))";
    $attr = array("dn, password, samaccountname");
    $dn = "DC=CORP,DC=COMPANY,DC=com";
    $result = ldap_search($ldap, $dn, $filter, $attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $result);

    // Now build second query to bind and authenticate as user.
    $ldap_dn_bind = $entries["0"]["dn"];
    echo $ldap_dn_bind;

    if($ubind = @ldap_bind($ldap, $ldap_dn_bind, $password)) {
        echo "bound as $user - $ldap_dn_bind<BR>\n\n"; // Works
        $u_attr = array("description, physicaldeliveryofficename, postaladdress, st, postalcode, title, telephonenumber, mobile, samaccountname, givenname, sn, company, displayname, employeetype, mail, manager, employeeID, KMADescription, terminationdate");
        $u_result = ldap_search($ldap, $dn, $filter, $u_attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
        echo "ldap search<BR>\n";
        $u_entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $u_result);
        echo "print u_entries";
        print_r($u_entries);
        echo "done";
    } else {
        die("failed to authenticate user");   
    }
```

This line:

```
    $u_result = ldap_search($ldap, $dn, $filter, $u_attr) or exit("Unable to search LDAP server");
```

seems to work as desired and no error about performing the ldap search.
$u_entries however contains the same information as $entries and this is where I'm having a problem. I'm trying to obtain details about the user and insert them into a local db if they're not already present.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before, check if your LDAP server lets external connections in.

Check your $dn variable if you're using emails only enter the stuff after the @ sign

Also be sure that your admin credentials

also this link helped me understand it a bit more:
https://github.com/Adldap2/Adldap2-Laravel/issues/224
**Note i worked with Laravel**

Comment: Yes, it's open as a co-worked has another app in CF which works fine doing the same thing essentially. I can connect, and bind as admin user. I perform a search as admin user to obtain the DN of the user I want to authenticate. I then bind with the DN previously obtained and the users password. This also works and thus authentication works. At this point, i want to perform a second ldap_search and pull some information about that user. This is where I'm having a problem and the u_results/u_entries and returning the results of the first ldap_search query for DN.

Comment: https://www.vertica.com/kb/LDAP-Authentication-Best-Practices/Content/BestPractices/LDAP-Authentication-Best-Practices.htm

under **LDAP Search and Bind Authentication** it says : This previous example searches for sAMAccountName, which must match the Vertica user login name. Only a single match can be made. If multiple users match, the login fails. The LDAP bind occurs upon a successful search.

Comment: So, should I retrieve all those details in the initial attributes and ldap_search rather than performing a second search? Not sure I understand.

Comment: everything that you want to get with an ldap should be in there yes, instead of performing 2 searches you should get every atrribute from one search

Answer (score -1):

My attributes array was incorrect and by definition ldap_search will ALWAYS return the DN. Problem resolved.